# No file found using custom container to train on azure ml

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to train on azureml using a custom docker container with azure-cli, using the below command:

```
az ml job create -f train.yaml --resource-group DefaultResourceGroup-EUS2 --workspace-name test1234
```

and the train.yaml is:

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandJob.schema.json
type: command

environment: 
  image: user2001.azurecr.io/test/train:latest

command: >- 
  python test_local.py


compute: azureml:test1234
```

Upon firing the above command I'm getting this error on azure ml jobs:

```
Error: python: can't open file 'test_local.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have checked in my docker image, test_local.py is present,I have also tried the following combination- "./test_local.py & /test_local.py"
The error still continues. Can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Edit:`docker run -it user2001.azurecr.io/test/train:latest python test_local.py`
on running this command the container executes, but same thing doesn't work on azureml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the /app prefix solved the issue,
so the final statement is

```
command: >- 
python /app/test_local.py
```